# How to get ID from Instagram URL using preg_match

Tags: php, instagram

i need to know how to preg_match ID from instagram URL

https://www.instagram.com/p/BrODgnXHlE6/?utm_source=ig_share_sheet&igshid=znsinsart176

i tried

preg_match('/https://www.instagram.com/p/(.*)/(.*)/U', $video_url, $matches);

```
$video_id = $matches[1];
```

But it is not working
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/BrODgnXHlE6/?utm_source=ig_share_sheet&igshid=znsinsart176";
preg_match('/https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/p\/(.+)\/(.+)/U', $url, $matches);
$id = $matches[1];
```

Comment: @ZbyněkHovorka If the answer helped you, please mark it as solved.

Comment: working with some changes /https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/(.+)\/(.+)\//U and link must have slash in last char in url https://www.instagram.com/p/BrODgnXHlE6 [ / ] < important or will fail